# How to finetune a closed generative huggingface model?

Tags: nlp, huggingface, finetuning

I want to finetune a huggingface pretrained model on our internal documentation in a way it stats answering related questions. I could not find the adequate tutorial.

Comment: Why aren't the [HuggingFace fine-tuning tutorials](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.11.0/notebooks.html) adequate?

Comment: I don't know which one is the best for my use case

Comment: "[Fine-tune DialoGPT on New Datasets and Languages](https://github.com/ncoop57/i-am-a-nerd/blob/master/_notebooks/2020-05-12-chatbot-part-1.ipynb)" seems like a good candidate.